# pulling in a collection with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to pull in a collection from the url attribute and am having some problems. It seems fetch() returns successfully, but then I cannot access the models in my collection with get(). I am using bbb and requireJS to develop my modules

```
var rooms = new Rooms.Collection(); // calls the rooms module
  rooms.fetch({success: function(){
      console.log(rooms.get(1)); // should output the first model
});
```

Here is my collection code in the rooms module:

```
Rooms.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Rooms.Model,
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/projects/meeting-room/app/data/rooms.json'
});
```

If I output rooms, everything turns out fine. But when I try for a specific model, that is when I get an error.

```
[{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "Ford",
    "occupied": false
},
{
    "id": 23458,
    "name": "Chevy",
    "occupied": false
},
{
    "id": 83565,
    "name": "Honda",
    "occupied": false
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `collection.get` method looks up a model by id. If you want to find a model by position, use [`collection.at`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-at) instead.

Also notice that array indices in javascript are `0`-based, so the first model can be found with:

```
var model = collection.at(0);
```

For convenience, Backbone collections also implement some of [underscore's array and collection methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods), including `first`. That means you can also find the first model with:

```
var model = collection.first();
```

Comment: Nitpicking, feel free to ignore me :) `collection.get` supports lookup by both id and cid since 0.9.9 (and replaces getByCid)

Comment: @nikoshr, so it does, but I didn't feel it was relevant to mention here. Shall your comment document this fact for visitors from the future.

Comment: collection.get(cid) definitely did not work for me. When I used the id attribute, it worked. Using collection.at(cid) also worked.

Comment: @Jeff, `.get(cid)` oughta work, `.at(cid)` might work by coincidence if `cid === index`. Are you using `>=0.9.9`?

Comment: Backbone.js 0.9.2. When I ran 'bbb init' that is what it gave me.

Comment: @Jeff, as nikoshr mentions in his initial comment, the cid lookup functionality was added to `collection.get` only in v0.9.9. Before that we had `collection.getByCid`.